# SQL Join a query with With clause

Tags: sql-server

I need to join 2 queries but I can't figure out how to because I added a `with` clause so the query makes it a bit more sense.

Here is the main query

```
    SELECT
    Id,
    Referencia,     
    UAP, 
    ConsumoWeek01 AS ConsumoWeek01, 
    ConsumoWeek02, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Stock IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE    
        Stock
    END AS Stock ,
    PecasPorCaixa
FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
    'SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.RH6001 ASC) AS Id,
        A.RH6001 as Referencia, 
        A.RH6002 as UAP, 
        A.RH6030 as ConsumoWeek01, 
        A.RH6031 as ConsumoWeek02,
        IC130M.LLBLT1 as Stock,
        0 AS PecasPorCaixa
    FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.TRP060H AS A
    LEFT JOIN AUTO.D805DATPOR.IC130M IC130M 
    ON A.RH6001 = IC130M.LLPPN AND
         IC130M.LLSTLC =
             CASE A.RH6002
                  WHEN ''UAP1'' THEN ''M1''
                  WHEN ''UAP2'' THEN ''M2''
                  WHEN ''UAP3'' THEN ''M3''
                  WHEN ''UAP4'' THEN ''M4''
                  WHEN ''UAP5'' THEN ''M5''
                  WHEN ''UAP6'' THEN ''M6''
                  WHEN ''UAPP'' THEN ''PROTOS''
                  WHEN ''EXT'' THEN ''EXTR''
                END     
    WHERE (A.RH6001 Not Like ''FS%'') 
    AND A.RH6030 <> 0
    ORDER BY Referencia DESC')
```

And here is the query I want to be left joined

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC,
    'WITH maxFornecedor AS
     (
        SELECT
            YDA3REP.A3ARCD,
            YDA3REP.A3D5CD,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY YDA3REP.A3D5CD ORDER BY YDA3REP.A3A3DT DESC) AS Number
        FROM
            AUTO.YSACHAPOR.YDA3REP YDA3REP
     )              
        SELECT 
            YDAUREP.AUD5CD,
            YDAUREP.AUQCON
        FROM maxFornecedor F
        join AUTO.YSACHAPOR.YDAUREP YDAUREP
        ON F.A3ARCD = YDAUREP.AUARCD
        AND F.A3D5CD = YDAUREP.AUD5CD
        WHERE F.Number = 1 AND YDAUREP.AUD5CD LIKE ''M%'' 
        AND YDAUREP.AUD5CD NOT LIKE ''%P%'' 
        AND YDAUREP.AUA0NB > 1 
        AND YDAUREP.AUG6ST=''O''                
')
```

I tried adding another `with` clause on 2nd query on the 2nd select but it does not work

Comment: The question is not clear. Show us the text of the query that you are trying to run and what error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

To add another CTE-Table use this Syntax:

```
with TableA 
AS (SELECT 1 AS [ColumnA])
, TableB 
AS (SELECT 2 AS [ColumnB])
```